# Matrix Algebra Question (Linear Algebra)

Tags: linear-algebra

Find all values of $a$ such that $A^3 = 2A$, where

$$A = \begin{bmatrix} -2 & 2 \\ -1 & a \end{bmatrix}.$$

The matrix I got for $A^3$ at the end didn't match up, but I probably made a multiplication mistake somewhere.

Comment: Please do not delete questions with good answers. Others have devoted effort to answer your question; deleting the question is disrespectful of their effort and prevents others from benefiting from your question and its answers.

Answer (score 30):

Hint:

$$A^3 = \begin{bmatrix} -4 + 2 (2 - a) & -2 (-4 + 2 a) + 2 (-2 + a^2) \\-2 + (2 - a) a &  4 - 2 a + a (-2 + a^2) \end{bmatrix}$$

$$2A = \begin{bmatrix} -4 & 4 \\-2 &  2 a \end{bmatrix}$$

Can you take it from here?

**Spoiler**

Hover over the blue area for the result.

> $a=2$ (Throw out the other solutions from equating the lower right items to solve for $a$).

Comment: What's that about the lower right? This is most easily seen by comparing the results in the upper left!

Comment: I could have used better terminology. If you equate $A_{2,2}^3$ to $2A_{2,2}$ and solve for $a$, there are 3 values. One works and the other two do not. All other positions only provide a single value. So we could have possibly had more than one solution. Regards

Comment: I think you're missing dfeuer's point. If you equate $A_{1,1}^3$ to $2A_{1,1}$ you get $-4 + 2(2-a) = -4$, which has one solution. Then it's just a case of checking it against the other three cells.

Comment: Yes, I looked at that when I originally solved it and all I am saying is that we needed a single solution, but that we also possibly had three, so I did not miss that. It happens that the $a$ that we find in all cases is coincident. Regards

Comment: No, you're still missing dfeuer's point. Because the solution has to work in all positions, once we see that the upper left has only one solution, **that's the only possible solution to the problem**, no matter what the other elements look like. The only thing that is left is to check whether $a=2$ works or not -- that there may be different numbers that work for some of the _other_ elements is immaterial, because they will fail in the upper left position anyway.

Answer (score 22):

Here's a different approach that avoids matrix multiplication in favor of determinants:

We want to find $a$ such that $A^3=2A$. This is equivalent to $A^3-2A=0$, and to $(A^2-2I)A=0$.

Thus either $A=0$, which is impossible, or $A^2-2I$ is a zero divisor.

Thus \begin{align}0&=\det (A^2-2I) \\ &= \det(A+\sqrt2I)\det(A-\sqrt2 I),\end{align} so one of these determinants must be $0$. That is, $(-2+\sqrt 2)(a+\sqrt 2)+2=0$ or $(-2-\sqrt 2)(a-\sqrt 2)+2=0$. These have the same sole solution: $a=2$.

Note that we get the value of $A^2$ too: plugging in $a=2$ gives $\det A = -2\ne 0$, so $A$ is *not* a zero divisor, so $A^2-2I=0$, so $A^2=2I$.

Comment: I don't follow. Since $x^3-2x$ annihilates the $2\times2$ matrix $A$, the minimal polynomial of $A$ could be $x,\ x-\sqrt{2},\ x+\sqrt{2},\ x(x-\sqrt{2}),\ x(x+\sqrt{2})$ or $x^2-2$. Among these six candidates, you only consider $x$ and $x^2-2$. Why?

Comment: @user1551, I don't know what a "minimal polynomial" is. $(A^2-2I)A=0$ implies that either $A=0$ or $\det(A^2-2I)=0$. $A$ obviously cannot be $0$, because it has non-zero constant entries.

Comment: I see. So, you are using abstract algebra terminology ('zero divisor') to refer to what is usually called 'noninvertible/singular matrix' in linear algebra. Thanks. +1

Comment: @user1551, would you mind telling me what a minimal polynomial is?

Comment: See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_polynomial_%28linear_algebra%29). A simple and routine solution (without tedious calculation of $A^3$) to the OP's problem would employ minimal polynomial, but your solution is admittedly even simpler.

Answer (score 2):

The matrix $A$ is clearly never a multiple of the identity, so its minimal polynomial is of degree$~2$, and equal to its characteristic polynomial, which is $P=X^2-(a-2)X+2-2a$. Now the polynomial $X^3-2X$ annihilates $A$ if and only if it is divisible by the minimal polynomial $P$. Euclidean division of $X^3-2X$ by $P$ gives quotient $X+a-2$ and remainder $(a^2-2a)X-(a-2)(2-2a)$. This remainder is clearly$~0$ if $a=2$ and for no other values of $a$, so $A^3=2A$ holds precisely for that value.

You can in fact avoid doing the Euclidean division by observing, since $X$ divides $X^3-2X$, that for $P$ to divide $X^3-2X$, unless $P$ itself has a factor $X$ (which happens for $a=1$ but divisibility then fails anyway), $P$ must divide (and in fact be equal to) $(X^3-2X)/X=X^2-2$; this happens for $a=2$.

Answer (score 2):

Any element of the set $\left\{\lambda\right\}$ of $A$ eigenvalues satisfy the equations

$$
\lambda^{2} = \left(a - 2\right)\lambda + 2\left(a - 1\right)\,,
\quad
\lambda^{3} = 2\lambda\,,
\quad
\sum_{\lambda}\lambda = a - 2
$$

Then, $\sum_{\lambda}\lambda^{3} = 2\left(a - 2\right)$. Also,
\begin{align}
\sum_{\lambda}\lambda^{3}
&=
\sum_{\lambda}\lambda\left[\left(a - 2\right)\lambda + 2\left(a - 1\right)\right]
=
\left(a - 2\right)\sum_{\lambda}\lambda^{2}
+
2\left(a - 1\right)\left(a - 2\right)
\\[3mm]&=
\left(a - 2\right)^{3} + 6\left(a - 1\right)\left(a - 2\right)
\end{align}
We get
$$
\left(a - 2\right)\left[\left(a - 2\right)^{2} + 6a - 8\right] = 0
$$

$$
\color{#ff0000}{\large%
a = 2\,,\qquad\qquad a = -1 \pm \sqrt{5\,}}
$$

Comment: How does a $2\times2$ matrix have $3$ eigenvalues?

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen That´s true. I have to think another way. Thanks.